# How to compute the length using the inner product?

Tags: inner-products

I am given a vector:

\begin{bmatrix}1\\-1\\3\end{bmatrix}

The inner product is defined:

$$ \langle \, f, \, g \, \rangle =a^\top\!* \begin{bmatrix}2&1&0\\1&2&-1\\0&-1&2\end{bmatrix} * b $$

How can I compute the length of the vector.

$ ||a||$ = $\sqrt{\langle a,a\rangle}$ = $\sqrt{ 2a(1)^2 +a(1)*a(2) +a(2)*a(1) +2a(2)^2 -a(3)*a(2)-a(3)*a(2) +a(3)^2}$ = $\sqrt{ 2 -1 -1+2+3+3+9}$

As the result, I got square root of 20, which is incorrect. Could anyone help me to find a mistake in my calculations?

Comment: You don't show any calculations.  "$20$" is not the value of the expression under the radical, but how can we guess where your error is since you do not show that calculation.

Comment: Have edited the question. There should be a mistake in the expression under the radical I guess.

Comment: It's not orthogonal.

Comment: If you would use the Pythagorean Theorem, what would the length then be? What course is this?

Comment: Linear Algebra Hilbert spaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see no way to get $20$ from what you wrote under the radical.  That expression evaluates to $17$.

Also, the algebraic expression under your radical has a bug:  it should be "$2 a(3)^2$".  (The diagonal of your matrix is $(2,2,2)$, so all the squared terms should have coefficient $2$.)  This would give an extra $9$ to your expression under the radical.

Let's try this computation a different way, which has an extra step, but is usually easier in each step.  Call your matrix $M$.  Then \begin{align*}
M.a &= (1, -4,7)  \\
a^\mathrm{T}.(M.a) &= \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \\ 3 \end{pmatrix} \cdot (1, -4, 7)  \\
    &= 26  \text{,}
\end{align*}
which should be the value under the radical.

Comment: That should be a reason of missing value. Thank you. I've achieved the same result while calculating straight away.